# Multiple http requests in a single Integromat module

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

Is it possible to make one request to get some data, and then make another request within a single module run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to perform multiple requests. Please take a look in the doc here https://docs.integromat.com/apps/structure-blocks/api/multiple-requests